# Why does Safari 5 misreport EM size?

Tags: css, safari, media-queries

I need to determine what a browser's default font size is, as I'm using em's in my layout, but am using quite a bit of javascript as well.

The problem is, Safari 5's default font-size seems to be independent of the em width in an unpredictable way.

So, when Safari's default font size is set to 14px, it reports a 1em div as being 16px. However, it uses the 14px value when calculating media queries. So a media query that's set for 20em will actually kick in at 280px, not 320px. This is problematic because in javascript, I have to supply an actual pixel value.

Why does Safari report a 1em div as being 16px wide, regardless of what the default font size is set to? Why isn't this value consistent with ems in media queries?

Comment: Does this help?  http://filamentgroup.com/lab/how_we_learned_to_leave_body_font_size_alone/

Comment: It's a good article but not really. The problem is that I can's seem to find a way to tell javascript what value or em media queries are working with. The easy way out is to just set break points in pixels but I'm trying to avoid that...

Comment: Which version of Safari? In Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 7, the `em` unit appears to be implemented correctly: when font size is set to 14 pixels in browser settings and a `div` is declared as being `1em` wide, with no padding and no border, it is 14 pixels wide. – If you are going to use pixel dimensions in JavaScript, why do you let basic font size to depend on browser settings?

Comment: This is on the Mac. My entire layout is responsive, so I'm using EM's everywhere. Javascript doesn't work with ems, only pixels.